# Can't open android application using google maps api

Tags: android, google-maps

Tittle says it all. I don't know why the avd can't open the app.

Image: http://gyazo.com/860c43fcd216e324d1e2338c2836c704.png

**Manifest:**

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <application   
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.friendfinder.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAJAx2Q7_ZHiQYBNnz41IgS0O9vmi7auXM" />
    </application>
    <user-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RealtiveLaout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.google.android.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:apiKey="AIzaSyAJAx2Q7_ZHiQYBNnz41IgS0O9vmi7auXM"
        />
</RealtiveLaout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a few things from the ["Specify settings in the Application Manifest"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#specify_settings_in_the_application_manifest) section

1) The permissions

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```

2)  You app permission

```
 <permission
      android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
      android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
```

3) the opengl requirement

```
<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

Comment: I tried all of that earlier, tried now again and keeps getting the same errors :/

Comment: Well that should definitely be in your manifest, so keep it in there if you are using a map. Please also post your activity code and the entire logcat. Are you sure it's located on the base package com.example.friendfinder?

Comment: Posted all. Yea it's all inside that package

Comment: You are missing MainActivity.java

Comment: Well, the class is named MapViewActivity, not MainActivity that's why you are getting the ClassNotFoundException. Either rename the Activity class, or modify the manifest

Comment: Changed <activity
            android:name="com.example.friendfinder.MainActivity"
to
<activity
            android:name="com.example.friendfinder.MapViewActivity"

still dont work

Comment: Can someone help me please i realy need this

Comment: You are using the old version of the google maps library (MapActivity and MapView). Read the whole documentation to use the V2.

Comment: I did, i tried many ways to do this and i can't get why it don't work

Comment: You have to use MapFragment or SupportMapFragment in order to add a map to your application. MapActivity doesn't exist on V2. Read https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#add_a_map_to_an_android_application

Comment: the error was in <RealtiveLaout it has to be <RelativeLayout. Thanks anyway guys